# What kind of SCSI terminator do I need?

Tags: scsi

I'm connecting a PowerVault 114T tape drive to a server with an Adaptec 29160 SCSI card. I know i need a terminator on the tape drive, but not sure exactly what kind I need. Do I need a multimode or SE terminator?

EDIT - Like @Chopper 3 said, the PowerVault 114T is an enclosure; the tape drive in it is a LTO-2-L(114T), it's a SCSI drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roads? Where we're going, we don't need roads!

Just google for an "active LVD SCSI terminator VHDCI male" where you live, as that's what you need for LVD and that particular drive.

EDIT - actually given the 114T is an enclosure that can take a range of different drives within it and it's the actual drives that define what connections you have (for instance you can put SAS drives in those if you want) then it depends on what drives you have inside if you need a terminator or not and if so what type. So let us know what type of drives you've got and we'll be able to be a little more certain. Thanks.

Comment: I'm hesitant to disagree with someone with such a high rating, but I'm pretty sure the interface on the tape drive is HD-68, not VHDCI; and that's where the terminator is needed, no?

Comment: Oh you shouldn't take that into concern, I'm as fallible as anyone! actually you made me go look up some more detail and as such I'm just about to make an edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Some drives have a dip switch you can set to enable termination in which case you do not need a separate terminator. (Note this is different than "enable terminator power" which is used when your HBA doesn't provide that power (most HBAs do).)